Irreducible Elements and Maximal Ideals
I am studying to my ring theory final exam and I have found this exercise:
"Let $R$ be an integral domain. Prove that: if $M=(a)$ is a non-zero maximal ideal of $R$, then $a$ is an irreducible element of $R$."
I already proved that.
Further on the exercise states: "Prove that the converse of the above statement is not true when $R$ is not an integral domain."
But I am really confused since looking for an answer, users talk about PID or UFD and I don't understand the relation. I understand that I have to look for an counterexample, a ring that is not an integral domain and find an irreducible element that does not "generate" a maximal ideal, but it turned out to be very difficult for me.
I really appreciate any hint to continue with this exercise.

The section "find an irreducible element that does not "generate" a maximal ideal" doesn't fit to the question.

An ideal generated by an irreducible element is a maximal non-trivial principal ideal, so an ideal generated by multiple elements may be a larger ideal.

@MartinBrandenburg I mean, to find an irreducible $a \in R$ such that $(a)$ is not a non-zero maximal ideal.

In fact, the converse does not hold true even when $R$ is an integral domain.
Take for example, the ring $R = \mathbf{C}[X,Y]$. The ideal generated by the irreducible element $X+Y$ is not maximal (it is contained in the maximal ideal $(X,Y)$ in $R$).
Edit: But to answer your question when $R$ is not an integral domain, consider the ring $R = \mathbf{C}[X,Y,Z]/((X+Y)^2 - Z^2)$. The ideal generated by the irreducible element $\bar{X}+ \bar{Y} - \bar{Z}$ in this ring is not maximal (as it is properly contained in the maximal ideal $(\bar{X},\bar{Y}, \bar{Z})$ in $R$).

I have edited my answer to give a counter-example when $R$ is not an integral domain.
